# Find a cell using input box then another input box to subtract from cell to the right in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a simple spread sheet to manage inventory. By using input boxes to find a part number in column A (this is a part number) then another input box to subtract the number entered in the second input box from the cell to the right of the found cell. (this is the inventory quantity). I am new to vba so be patient. This is what I have so far. I can find the part number but am stuck on how to subtract the quantity.

```
Sub Find_First()
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Bog As Range
    FindString = InputBox("Scan Barcode Or Enter Part Number")
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Inventory").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
            Else
                MsgBox "Part number not found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: please post the code in the question (indent 4 spaces)